How to mute parts of the video without using professional software?
I want to eliminate some of the swearing in the video and leave the rest untouched. I don't want to cover the swearing with other sounds, just mute the swearing. That's the only thing I need, and I'm a novice at video editing.
I only have a laptop with an AMD RYZEN 5600 cpu so I may not be able to run professional software. Online tools or simple software may be better.
Thank you for your patience in reading my question.

are you running windows? You need some video editing software. Capcut, Davinci Resolve, Premiere, or something else
